# This is not a problem vs. This is less of a problem

Tags: word-meaning

I usually use "This is not a problem" so as to mean that it is not a big deal.
But I saw "This is less of a problem" from a book. So, I wonder how different they are.
Is the second one valid only when there is a counter part to compare?

Comment: Yeah, I think the "less" makes it comparative, comparing it with whatever other big problem you have to deal with instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their literal meanings are very different; the first sentence indicates that "this" is not a problem, while the second indicates that it is. ("Less of a problem" is still a problem.) You might be using the first sentence figuratively, though; in that case, the intended meanings might be similar. It's hard to tell without context.

Yes, the second sentence is valid only when there is a counterpart to compare. As Riolku notes, "less" is a comparative word, so it implies that two things are being compared.